# Set compulsory field for an object

Tags: java, object, field

I am working on my pet ownership system and struggle at a problem. To add a resident object, I need 5 fields which are phone, postcode, name, birthday and pet. Among them, phone, postcode, and name are compulsory fields, and the others are optional. An object can only be built with the existence of compulsory fields.

How can I do that, to differentiate between compulsory and optional fields? I just taught myself the OOP system. Really need a hint. Any answer is welcome!

Comment: Are you using GUI or CLI?

Comment: I am using CLI.

Comment: Please include the Java code you have tried.  Your question is a bit vague as it is now.

Comment: You should define a constructor which has your compulsory fields as the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to make sure through prompt(user input) or string check(file input) if the input has the correct fields needed to correctly create your object(class)
After this use a programmer defined constructor 
Documentation for that in the link
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

to instantiate the object using the needed fields and I would use Set functions for optional inputs.

If the inputs do not match the needed inputs output a fail message and do not instantiate the object.

I hope this helps with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**This is just an example of how you could approach the problem**

```
public class Example{
String phone;
String postcode;
String name;
String birthday;
String pet;

public Example()
{
    birthday="N/A";
    pet="N/A";
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Ask phone number
    while(phone==null||phone=="")
    {
        //keep on asking
    }

    //Ask postcode
    while(postcode==null||postcode=="")
    {
        //keep on asking
    }

    //Ask name
    while(name==null||name="")
    {
        //keep on asking
    }

    //Ask birthday, and no need for checks
    //Ask pet, and no need for checks

}
}
```